# Fixed Menu slidingFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-sliding

I have an app that implements sliding menu from jfeinstein10, but i can't make the menu remains fixed until the user does something. Any ideas? For example, when click a item on listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!! I did the following:

to disable menu:

```
getSlidingMenu()setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
```

and to enable the menu:

```
getSlidingMenu()setTouchModeBehind(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
```